# Increase NSDate +1 day method Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

This is my method I use for increasing by one day in my navigationBar, and setting the name of the day as a title. I know it's wrong because I set "today" variable every time its called. But I can't figure out how to increase +1 day every time I call this method.

```
-(void)stepToNextDay:(id)sender
{
    today = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *datePlusOneDay = [today dateByAddibgTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24)];
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatterBehaviour = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePlusOneDay];
    self.navigationItem.title = datestring;
}
```

Comment: In the navigationBar i have 2 buttons which I use for navigate thru days in the week. This method is called when I want to display "next day". For every day i browse to I request data from a Web Service and populate the tableviewCell.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Store the date your are showing in a property (ivar, ...) of your view controller. That way you can retrieve the current setting when you go to the next day.

If you want to reliably add dates, use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to get a "1 day" unit, and add that to the current date.

```
NSCalendar*       calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents* components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
components.day = 1;
NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate: self.date options: 0];
```

Comment: You're lucky, I'm feeling helpful today :)

Answer (score 3):

As from iOS 8 `NSGregorianCalendar` is depricated, the updated answer will be,

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = 1;
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
```

**Swift Code:**

```
var today:NSDate = NSDate()
let calender:NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
var components:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay)
var newDate:NSDate! = calender.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate:today, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
```